# Flight flown + operated by completely different, non-code-share airline?

Tags: airlines, vietnam, low-cost-carriers, vueling

Yesterday (March 3) I flew Jetstar Pacific 596 from SGN to DAD. The airplane contained markings for vueling.com, the crew was wearing vueling uniforms, and despite being a domestic flight in Vietnam, flight announcements were made in English and Spanish. As far as I can tell, Vueling is a low cost carrier in Spain and this wasn't a code share flight.

It looks like this may have been the plane: https://m.planespotters.net/airframe/Airbus/A320/5940/EC-LZF-Jetstar-Pacific-Airlines

Can anyone explain what is going on? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: This may be better suited for the Aviation site, if so and you are a moderator can you move it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Airlines wet lease aircraft all the time (wet lease being a lease that includes crew, maintenance, pilots, etc versus a dry lease which is aircraft only).  If the lease is long term, then often the plane is painted to match the leasing airline's look and flight crews are provided with uniforms.  But if the lease is short term, say filling the need for an increase in flights during a certain season or perhaps a delay in delivery of a new aircraft, then the aircraft may not be repainted.

Comment: In short, the actual flight was outsourced to another airline.

Comment: @Cronax - one could also use the less derogatory term of sub-contracted.  But the airline industry term is wet lease.

Comment: @Tom This is the first time I heard from anyone that "outsourcing" is a derogatory term.

Comment: @Malcolm You must not work in IT.

Comment: @Mark Couldn't be further from the truth. I don't see anything wrong with the term itself though. Yes, I know that outsourcers often do a lousy job, but when they do, you can call the practice whatever you want, this won't improve the matters a bit.

Comment: @Malcolm - 'outsourcing' is often used as a negative term, not a positive one.  And the curt sentence it was used in left that feeling.

Comment: @Mark Maybe IT upper management?  Associations with that term vary a lot depending on perspective.

Comment: @Mark It is negative because of its nature, it has nothing to do with the term itself. And no, subcontracting is not the same as subcontractors typically specialize in a specific area for which the general contractor cannot provide the services himself. That is clearly not the case with two airlines. Cronax mentions outsourcing because it is outsourcing, doesn't matter if someone invented a different name for that.

Comment: @Malcolm The derogatory nature of the word may also be regional. I notice that you are from Russia while Mark is from the US. Here in America the word "outsourcing" generally also includes the implication of taking away American jobs and giving them to cheap labor in other countries.

Comment: @DavidK I lived in the US for several years, and the same practice happens here too, so I know what he might mean, but that doesn't mean that we should stop calling things by their names just because the business practice may sometimes have a negative side.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36576/discussion-on-answer-by-tom-flight-flown-operated-by-completely-different-non).